# Javascript - remove child or parent elements from an array

Tags: javascript

I got a code to remove child/parent elements from a random array that might contain both a child and a parent element, for example:

```
<html>

    <body>
        <div id='1'>
            <div id='2'>
                <div id='3'>
                </div>
                <div id='4'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='5'>
            <div id='6'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>

arr = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
// arr: [<div#1>,<div#2>, <div#3>, <div#4>, <div#5>, <div#6>]
```

So from this example how can I extract the children:

```
// arr: [<div#3>, <div#4><div#6>]
```

Or extract the parents:

```
// arr: [<div#1>, <div#5>]
```

currently I'm using:

```
function isDescendant(parent, child) {
     var node = child.parentNode;
     while (node != null) {
         if (node == parent) {
             return true;
         }
         node = node.parentNode;
     }
     return false;
}

function filterArray(arr, parent=true){
    newArr = [];
    arr.forEach((a)=>{
        bool = true

        if (parent){
            arr.forEach((b)=>{
                if (isDescendant(a, b)){
                    bool = false
                };
            });
        }
        else{
            arr.forEach((b)=>{
                if (isDescendant(b, a)){
                    bool = false
                };
            });            
        }

        if(bool){
            newArr.push(a)
        }
    });
    return newArr
};
```

But I'm pretty sure there could be a better solution, more efficient.
Any idea for a better solution?

Comment: Would get rid of a lot of parents right away using selector `div > div`

Comment: `parent.contains(child)` is another way of doing `isDescendant(parent, child)`

Comment: thanks @jspcal, nice to know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have a method called [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which lets you do just that; filter an array. To find if a node is a parent or child of another node, you can either use the [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)-method (note that this might return true when checking if a node contains itself), or the more generic [`compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition)-method.

```js
const nodes = Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll("div"));

//The most straight-forward way to find the parents, 
//filter out any nodes where no other node in the array contains it 
//(note the m !== n check, which prevents contains to return true for the same node):
let parents = nodes.filter( n => !nodes.find( m => m !== n && m.contains(n) ));
//Conversely, to find any child-nodes, invert the contains-check to find any nodes that does not contain any other node in the array:
let children = nodes.filter( n => !nodes.find( m => m !== n && n.contains(m) ));
console.log("approach 1:\n", parents, "\n", children);

//Here is the same approach using compareDocumentPosition instead of contains:
parents = nodes.filter( n => !nodes.find(m => m.compareDocumentPosition(n) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY) );
children = nodes.filter( n => !nodes.find(m => n.compareDocumentPosition(m) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY) )

console.log("approach 2:\n", parents, "\n", children);

//And finally, if you don't need the restriction of checking against 
//elements in the array, you can just see if the nodes have 
//the topmost parent/any children at all:
const topElement = document.body;
parents = nodes.filter( n => n.parentElement === topElement );
children = nodes.filter( n => !n.childElementCount );
console.log("approach 3:\n", parents, "\n", children);
```

```html
<div id='1'>
  <div id='2'>
    <div id='3'>
    </div>
    <div id='4'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='5'>
  <div id='6'>
  </div>
</div>
```

A quick benchmark reveals the last method to be fastest (at least on my machine) (no surprise, it doesn't have to search the array multiple times), followed by the `contains`-version. The slowest is using `compareDocumentPosition`, but that is still faster than running `filterArray` to get the child array.

Answer (score 0):

For children can convert collection to array and `filter()` using `querySelector()` which won't return anything when element isn't a parent

For outer parents can use `Array#some()` and `node#contains()` as filter()

```js
const arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div'));

const innerChildren = arr.filter(el => !el.querySelector('*')); // or use same selector as master query

const outerParents = arr.filter(e => !arr.some(el => el !== e && el.contains(e)));

console.log(innerChildren) // div#3, div#4 & div#6  
console.log(outerParents) //  div#1, div#5
```

```html
<div id='1'>
  <div id='2'>
    <div id='3'></div>
    <div id='4'></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='5'>
  <div id='6'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following. It pick the right answers although not generic. Hope works for your case. Should be with less data loops under scene too.

```
const nodes = Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll("div"));

const children = nodes.filter( node => 0 === node.querySelectorAll('div').length );
const parents = nodes.filter( node => 'DIV' !== node.parentNode.nodeName );
```

Here is JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3nhzvat9/

and another solution that should perform even better:

```
const nodes = document.body.querySelectorAll("div");
const children = [];
const parents = [];

nodes.forEach( node => {
   if(0  === node.querySelectorAll('div').length) {
      children.push(node);
   }
   if('DIV' !== node.parentNode.nodeName){
     parents.push(node);
   }
});
```

second JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3nhzvat9/1/